# how to get c# shown even after button X was hit?

Tags: c#, events, show

I need my form to hide after hitting the close because I do not want to re construct it so I do this.

```
 private void dLCD_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            e.Cancel = true; 
        }
```

To bring my window back up I use .show().  Though, shown is not called but the first time. I can not seem to find any events that will fire after calling .show(). My best guess was for the activated event to fix this but it does not do anything. I considered using a flag and something like getFocus but it too is not called on .show()

I can not seem to find a good solution.

Comment: Why is reconstructing the form not an option? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why can't you do `Form.Close()` and `Form.Show()` whenever you want to close/open it?

Comment: I'm agree with @ emsimpson92, probably the best option is to rebuild the form every time you need it, however, if you want a event that triggers with every show, you could use "Activated" event.

Comment: Did you try closing and reconstructing it and it was slow or something? If you did not try it and it does not affect performance then why are you making your life more difficult? Just close it and recreate it when you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose that you use Form.VisibleChanged event instead. That event is fired every time the visibility of the form changed. So, you'll need to have a flag to determine when you want to execute the startup code (the code you have actually in the shown event).

Example to give you an idea of what the events handlers could look like :

```
 private void Form1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            if (_isClosing)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                // Code when form is shown
            }

            _isClosing = false;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
            _isClosing = true;
            e.Cancel = true;
            Hide();
    }
```